# Can my drones be destroyed in X-Rebirth?

Tags: x-rebirth

The X-Rebirth drone flying mechanic is interesting: it's kind of neat to explore the system from far away (although that has put me in positions where my ship has taken damage while I was playing drone pilot).  My question is: can my drones be destroyed?  It seems like drones *bamf* back to your hold if you hit escape, no matter how far they are from the ship.  Is it possible for an enemy to kill one faster that you can hit the key?  Can they be destroyed at all?  Is there a max distance for them to teleport back to your drone hangar?

Comment: I have taken some fire in a combat drone. Saw no indication of damage and wasn't destroyed. Kills me how the only indication we get that our ship is under attack is the 'shields critical' warning though.

Comment: One of my Assasin drones taken damage, and it persisted between uses (it shows 35 instead 100 hull). I think it will be destroyed eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Any drone can be destroyed, utility drones usually have about 1000 hull points. Attack drones have more, depending on model.

If you recall your drone (hit ESC), it will remain damaged next time you use it.

3.0 update changed drone behaviour and drones now fly to Player Ship for docking when you exit remote control.

Max distance for remote control is 20 km. If you cross this distance, then drone will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

When your drone gets hit all the damage is funneled to the skunk.  I dont think it was intended to work this way, but that seems to be what is happening.  Luckily the drone is a small target so your ship wont likely be destroyed if you make a decent effort to avoid enemy fire.